# Handling errors in ANTLR 4

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr

After following the [accepted answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137301/2279200) instructions of [Handling errors in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18132078/2279200) question I stuck up with the following error.

> CustomErrorListener.java:11: cannot find symbol
>      symbol  : variable REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS
>     location: class CustomErrorListener

I understood that ways to handle errors in ANTLR4 were different from ANTLR3,  and based on the aforementioned question and its answers I ended up implementing the following error listener.

```
public class DescriptiveErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {
    public static DescriptiveErrorListener INSTANCE = new DescriptiveErrorListener();

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol,
                        int line, int charPositionInLine,
                        String msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        if (!REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS) {
            return;
        }

        String sourceName = recognizer.getInputStream().getSourceName();
        if (!sourceName.isEmpty()) {
            sourceName = String.format("%s:%d:%d: ", sourceName, line, charPositionInLine);
        }

        System.err.println(sourceName+"line "+line+":"+charPositionInLine+" "+msg);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I could not find anything about this `REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS` field anywhere in the ANTLR documentation. Any clue on what this could come from?

Comment: The symbol is in your code, it's the first line of your method.  You wrote `if (!REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS) {`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, it must refer to some inherited field from a parent class I reckon, but I don't know what it is not where it come from. Intuitively I guess it must check if there is actually an error, otherwise return without doing anything (which I noticed when I commented it out and I has loads of NullPointerException), but I don't know why it does not compile nor what to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's declared in the [same file](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/TestPerformance.java) you copied and pasted the `DescriptiveErrorListener` class from. Here is the declaration:

```
private static final boolean REPORT_SYNTAX_ERRORS = true;
```

When the value is `false`, the `syntaxError` method returns without displaying errors.