# Parse a formula using ANTLR4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse a mathematical formula to a subset of LaTeX using ANTLR4. For example it should parse `(a+4)/(b*10)` to `\frac{a+4}{b\cdot 10}`.

My simple grammar creates a tree like this:

[image: antlr tree]

Now I am trying to implement parse tree listeners to somehow construct the LaTeX String while the tree is traversed. Here, I am failing because to construct a String like `\frac{}{}` it has to be built recursively. The parse tree walker, however, visits one tree node after the other (in a breadth-first way as far as I can tell).

I've read about parse tree *visitors* that might be what I need. But I wasn't able to find some examples how these visitors are applied.

Could you provide an example how parse tree listeners/visitors can be used in this particular case? Do you think my approach to use ANTLR for the parser makes sense in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a parse tree walker by implementing the `ParseTreeVisitor` interface. For ease of use, you can specify Antlr to generate a base visitor when compiling the grammar (in Antlrworks, `Run->Generate Recognizer->Next->Generate Visitor->Next->Finish`). The base visitor will be called `MyGrammarBaseVisitor`. Note that the visitor has a generic type T, which every single visit method should return. I recommend using `Void` for manual manipulation or `String` for ease of use during code generation.

After you extend the base visitor (I'll assume here we're dealing with `String`), you need to override the visit methods. These methods are named after the grammar rules you have. Each of these methods will receive a `ParserContext ctx` parameter, which you use to visit child rules and/or get terminal values. For example, you could do this:

```
class MyVisitor extends MyGrammarBaseVisitor<String> {
    @Override
    public String visitMultiplicative(MyGrammarParser.MultiplicativeContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.opMult().getText().equals("/")) return "\\frac{" + visit(ctx.expr(0)) + "}{" + visit(ctx.expr(1)) + "}";
        else return visit(ctx.expr(0)) + "\\cdot " + visit(ctx.expr(1));
    }
    // visit methods for other rules...
}
```

I'm assuming your `multiplicative` rule looks like `multiplicative: expr opMult expr; opMult: '*' | '/';` You can find more information in [The Definitive Antlr 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference). You may also find more information and examples in the [Antlr documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+4+Documentation).

Comment: This works great, thank you! I'm now using Antlrworks like you suggested (I compiled the grammar in the command line before) and now the `*Visitor` classes are properly created.

Comment: @Mouagip you can still do that in command-line, just use the `-visitor` argument! See: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+Tool+Command+Line+Options

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But using Antlrworks directly as NetBeans plugin is more convenient now ;-) Still, the command line will be an option for a possible build script.