# antlr4 - Parsing ALPHANUMERIC that starts with alphabets

Tags: antlr4

I have the following ABNF rule for string definition.

```
STRING   = ALPHA *(allowedchar)

allowedchar   = "-" / "_" / DIGIT / ALPHA

ALPH = A-Z ,a-z
```

Valid tokens:

```
aa1
a_1___a
a23
a
a-1
a_a
```

(if first char is alpha, then reset can be any char form 'allowedchar')

Invalid tokens:

```
-e
--
-1
-a
--1
--a
1
```

(doesn't starts with Alphabets).

So far, I have the grammar works for all the inputs(both valid and invalid) except `"--a"` and `"__a"`.

ANTL4 accepts this token as valid strings.

I am not sure why this is not working.

My Grammar

```
STRING : ALPHANUMERIC
ALPHA           : [a-zA-Z]+ ;

fragment ALPHANUMERIC : ALPHA (ALLOWEDATTCHAR)* ;

fragment ALLOWEDATTCHAR : '-' | '_' | [0-9] | ALPHA ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ANTL4 accepts this token as valid strings.

I doubt that.

Assuming your `ALPHA` rule looks like this:

```
fragment ALPHA : [a-zA-Z];
```

I'm sure ANTLR does *not* tokenize `"--a"` or `"__a"` as a `STRING`.

Check the output stream ANTLR is writing errors/warnings to: chances are ANTLR is informing you about something that goes wrong, and then recovers from it and continues parsing/lexing.

### EDIT

If you want to override ANTLR default error-handling/reporting, see: [Handling errors in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132078/handling-errors-in-antlr4)

Comment: ALPHA: [a-zA-Z]+ ; It parsing as "a" and called visiter implementation methods, where context.getText() is returning just "a". I expect the behaviour should make the token invalid and call BaseErrorListener.syntaxError(..).

Comment: Thanks Bart Kiers, after adding error handler for Parser and lexer, I was able to report error.