# Antlr : suppress console logs from antlr

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr

I want to catch the ANTLR errors in some way and suppress them showing up in my java logs.

I am beginner in ANTLR and using **ANTLR3.4**

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132078/handling-errors-in-antlr4) and I could not find any methods like these.

```
lexer.removeErrorListeners();
lexer.addErrorListener(someListener());
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(someListener());
```

Is there a way that I could to suppress ANTLR console error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ANTLR 3, you need to [override `BaseRecognizer.emitErrorMessage`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/4be10fb0b88143a6edfd91001c9487eb62ff21e8/runtime/Java/src/main/java/org/antlr/runtime/BaseRecognizer.java#L342-L345) to control the way errors are printed. The listener mechanism was added in ANTLR 4 (which I highly encourage you to use as it's vastly superior to ANTLR 3).