# Correct way to add custom exception to Lexer/Parser files in antlr4

Tags: java, parsing, error-handling, exception, antlr4

I have a custom 
ParsingException(String message, int location, String offendingText)

I want my parser to throw this exception when a parsing / lexing error is encountered.

Is this correct ?

```
@parser::members
{
  @Override
  public void notifyErrorListeners(Token offendingToken, String msg, RecognitionException ex)
  {
  throw new ParsingException(msg,offendingToken.getStartIndex(),offendingToken.getText());
  }
}
@lexer::members {
    @Override
    public void recover(RecognitionException ex)
    {
 throw new ParsingException(ex.getMessage(),getCharPositionInLine(),ex.getOffendingToken().getText());
        }
          }
```

I get an UnhandledException error with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `syntaxError` method of `BaseErrorListener` instead of `notifyErrorListeners` and `recover` as it decribed here: [Handling errors in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18132078/1046374).

Comment: ok, but if I do lexer.addErrorListener(ThrowingParsingExceptionErrorListener.INSTANCE); how can I get the offending text since the offendingSymbol is null ? Thanks