# ANTLR turns useful error messages into "no viable alternative" when I try to add custom error messages

Tags: java, antlr4

I am writing an ANTLR grammar for an esoteric programming language. I am trying to add custom error messages that would be outputted when certain forms of syntax are written.

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
grammar Foo;

OPEN_BRACE: '{';
CLOSE_BRACE: '}';
SEMI_COLON: ';';
PERIOD: '.';
WS: ' ' -> skip;
NOOP: 'noop';

statements
    : NOOP
    | NOOP SEMI_COLON statements
    // other kind of statements
    ;

program
    : OPEN_BRACE
      statements
      CLOSE_BRACE
      EOF
```

Suppose I want to output a custom error message if `program` ends with a `SEMICOLON` or when there are no `statements` in the braces. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58115099/5133585), I added some error alternatives:

```
program
    : OPEN_BRACE
      statements
      CLOSE_BRACE
      EOF
    | invalidPrograms
    ;

invalidPrograms
    : OPEN_BRACE
      statements
      CLOSE_BRACE
      SEMI_COLON
      EOF { notifyErrorListeners($SEMI_COLON, "program must not end with semicolon!", null); }
    | OPEN_BRACE
      CLOSE_BRACE
      EOF { notifyErrorListeners($OPEN_BRACE, "program must have at least one statement!", null); }
    ;
```

I then use an `ErrorListener` to collect all the errors the parser and lexer generates.

This works, but it also makes the other, default error messages generated by ANTLR all turn into a single "no viable alternative" message. For example, if I try to parse the syntactically invalid:

```
{noop
```

Before I added the error alternatives, it would produce a very useful error message:

```
line 1:5 missing '}' at '<EOF>'
```

Or if I write

```
{noop.}
```

The error messaging says:

```
line 1:5 extraneous input '.' expecting '}'
```

which is rather descriptive. However, if I add in the error alternatives, the error messages become:

```
line 1:5 no viable alternative at input...
```

which is undesirable. How can I keep the good error messages, while still using error alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding these rules, you're, inadvertently, undermining some of the power of ANTLRs error reporting and error recovery (by adding in rules that are "valid" to the parser, specifically, by making `<EOF>` valid).

Generally, both of the examples you're trying to add would usually be considered semantic errors.  It's better to handle these in your own code by evaluating your parser tree using either a listener or visitor.

There can be valid uses for introducing rules to match specific erroneous syntax to facilitate generation of more user-friendly error messages, but you have to be careful to avoid undermining the parser error recovery like this.

In general, you want a parser that is relatively "accepting" but unambiguous in it's proper interpretation of your input.  From that parse tree you can then look for semantic errors like those you've identified.  (It's a bit of a common temptation to put "as much as possible" into the grammar, but this can backfire (as you've seen))