# antlr4 nodes without labels

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am parsing the grammar with Antlr 4 (v4.9.2)

The following is the grammar:

```
grammar Test;

start
:
    command+ EOF
;
command: commandType params ;
commandType: 'DISPLAY' ;
params: param (',' param)*
    | ;//parameter list
param: ID;
ID : [a-z]+[a-z0-9]*
;
WS
:
    [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
;
```

The input text for the grammar is:

```
DISPLAY hello, really, sdfdsf
DISPLAY one more now
```

The following is the parse tree generated.
(start (command (commandType DISPLAY) (params (param hello) , (param really) , (param sdfdsf))) (command (commandType DISPLAY) (params (param one))) **more now** )

The nodes "more now" is not labelled.

Why the parser did not throw error for "more now"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* produce an error, but ANTLR's default strategy is to (try to) recover from invalid input, and continue parsing.

This is what is displayed when trying to parse your input:

[image]

[image]

Try Google for "ANTLR error strategy", "ANTLR error handling", or look at this Q&A: [Handling errors in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132078/handling-errors-in-antlr4)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bart Kiers. This is awesome feature, which I didn't realise.

Comment: Hi @Bart Kiers, how did you display the parse tree in GUI? any links or tool name.

Comment: @ArockDurai I used IntelliJ with the ANTLR4 plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4 . Note that the plugin works with most of Jetbrains' IDE's (PyCharm, Rider, Webstorm, ...), not just with IntelliJ.

Comment: Oh, I’m a bit of a JetBrains fan-boy, but there’s also VS Code that has a plugin that looks really nice: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4